# tcl script to compare 2 texts and return the line numbers of the lines that differ only. Also, How to avoid "child process exit abnormally"?

Tags: diff, exec, tcl

can anybody guide me how to write tcl script to compare 2 texts and return the line numbers of the lines that differ only ? 
I know how to do it in bash, but to include the bash in tcl doesnt seem to be very neat, here's the bash command :

```
    diff --old-line-format '%L' --new-line-format '' --unchanged-line-format ''  <(nl File1) <(nl File2) | awk '{print $1 }' > difflines
```

To include this in tcl, i did the following :

```
exec cat nl File1 > File11
exec cat nl File2 > File22
exec diff --old-line-format {%L} --new-line-format {} --unchanged-line-format {}  < 
File11 < File22 | awk {{print $1 }} > difflines
```

Is there a cleaner way ?

Also if there's difference i get the "child exit abnormally", how can i avoid this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`struct::list`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/struct_list.html) package in [Tcllib](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/) has tools for computing longest-common-subsequences, which is the key part of a `diff` tool. To use, you load your data into Tcl and split it into a list of lines:

```
proc getLines {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set result [split [read $f] "\n"]
    close $f
    return $result
}
```

Then you can get the information about the common elements (== common lines):

```
set sharedLineInfo [struct::list longestCommonSubsequence $file1_lines $file2_lines]
```

This returns a pair of lists, where each list is the indices (counting from *zero*) of the common lines; the first list will be for the first file, and the second list for the second file. Any line number not listed will be one that has changed.

There's also a function to invert the information provided to get instructions on how to change one sequence into the other:

```
set changes [struct::list lcsInvert $sharedLineInfo \
        [llength $file1_lines] [llength $file2_lines]]
```

This returns a list of triples, where the first is the operation performed (`added`, `changed` or `deleted`) and the second and third are the ranges of indices in each of the relevant lists (i.e., zero-based line numbers).

I'm not *quite* sure how to take this information and produce what you are looking for, but I guess we could put it together like this:

```
package require struct::list
proc getLines {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set result [split [read $f] "\n"]
    close $f
    return $result
}
proc variedLines {filename1 filename2} {
    set l1 [getLines $filename1]
    set l2 [getLines $filename2]
    lassign [struct::list longestCommonSubsequence $l1 $l2] common1
    set result {}
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $l1]} {incr i} {
        if {$i ni $common1} {
            lappend result [expr {$i + 1}]
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

If you want the results written to a file, `puts $f [join $someList "\n"]` is likely to feature, but I'll leave that as an exercise…

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "child process exited abnormally", from the [`exec` man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) (emphasis mine):

> If any of the *commands in the pipeline exit abnormally* or are killed or suspended, then *exec will return an error* and the error message will include the pipeline's output followed by error messages describing the abnormal terminations; the -errorcode return option will contain additional information about the last abnormal termination encountered. If any of the *commands writes to its standard error* file and that standard error is not redirected and -ignorestderr is not specified, then *exec will return an error*; the error message will include the pipeline's standard output, followed by messages about abnormal terminations (if any), followed by the standard error output.

"commands exit abnormally" means that the command exits with a non-zero status. Some common commands like grep and diff return a non-zero exit status to indicate something normal, so you have to wrap that exec call in a `catch`

```
set rc [catch {exec bash -c {
    diff --old-line-format '%L' --new-line-format '' --unchanged-line-format ''  <(nl File1) <(nl File2) | awk '{print $1}' > difflines
}} output]

if {$rc == 0} {
    puts "no differences found"
} elseif {$rc == 1} {
    puts "differences found:"
    puts $output
} else {
    puts "diff returned an error: $output"
}
```